# IBM Worklight - Offline storage for Windows environment

Tags: windows, environment, ibm-mobilefirst, offline-caching

I want to create an offline storage using IBM Worklight in the Windows environment.

Usually we will use JSONStore for offline storage but that works only for the iOS and Android environments.

1. Can anyone suggest a solution for offline storage for the above?
2. Also can we create applications for windows 7 desktop environments using IBM Worklight v5.0.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Worklight 5.0.5.x:

- Vista/Win7 gadgets
- Windows Phone 7.0

In Worklight 5.0.6.x:

- Vista/Win7 gadgets **deprecated** (removed in Worklight 6.0)
- Windows Phone 7.5
- Windows Phone 8
- Windows 8

As you've mentioned, JSONStore is available only for Android and iOS; you can instead use [IBM Worklight Encrypted Offline Cache](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/05_07_Storing_sensitive_data_in_Encrypted_Cache.pdf), or the [HTML5 standard Application Cache](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp).

Comment: we are currently using work light 5.0.5 but win7 gadgets are deprecated in it. so what can we do?

Comment: Deprecated means it will still work, but no support is given and it will be removed in the next version. It is your decision whether or not you want to continue working with this environment.

Comment: @usha, if your question has been answered, kindly mark this as Answered.

Comment: Actually with encrypted cache and HTML5 web storage its possible to store only 5-10MB of data. But we need to store large data. Is there any feature for storing large data as offline for windows environment?

Comment: Not one that Worklight provides. I do not know of such a solution either.